# AVPlayerViewController fails to play remote video with no error

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avkit

Have trouble with playing video file picked in picker controller, uploaded to server. "https://starfish.chat/attachment/112/253.mov"

Then just downloaded video and added to project. It plays.

`AVPlayerViewController` delegate methods newer called.

Controller look like this:
[image]

```
if let playerController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("player_controller_id") as? AVPlayerViewController {

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        let s = "https://starfish.chat/attachment/112/253.mov"
        let url2 = NSURL(string: s)

        let p = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("253", ofType: "mov")
        let url3 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: p!)

        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: url2!)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(nil, object: playerItem, queue: nil, usingBlock: { (notification) -> Void in
                            print("ERROR: " + (playerItem.error?.description ?? "") + "\n")
                            print("LOG: " + (playerItem.errorLog()?.debugDescription ?? "") + "\n")
                            print("ACCESS: " + (playerItem.accessLog()?.debugDescription ?? "") + "\n")
                        })

        let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

        playerController.player = player

        if #available(iOS 9, *) {
            playerController.delegate = self
        }

        self.presentViewController(playerController, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in

                        })
    } catch {}
}
```

Logs:

```
ERROR: 

LOG: <AVPlayerItemErrorLog: 0x15dbd0ef0>
#Version: 1.0
#Software: AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.13D15 (iPhone; U; CPU OS 9_2_1 like Mac OS X; uk_ua)
#Date: 2016/02/17 18:08:02.002

ACCESS: <AVPlayerItemAccessLog: 0x15db5a970>
#Version: 1.0
#Software: AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.13D15 (iPhone; U; CPU OS 9_2_1 like Mac OS X; uk_ua)
#Date: 2016/02/17 18:08:02.002

ERROR: 

LOG: <AVPlayerItemErrorLog: 0x15daa3380>
#Version: 1.0
#Software: AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.13D15 (iPhone; U; CPU OS 9_2_1 like Mac OS X; uk_ua)
#Date: 2016/02/17 18:08:02.002

ACCESS: <AVPlayerItemAccessLog: 0x15daa93f0>
#Version: 1.0
#Software: AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.13D15 (iPhone; U; CPU OS 9_2_1 like Mac OS X; uk_ua)
#Date: 2016/02/17 18:08:02.002
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix the issue you were having?

Comment: @AndyRyan, that was actually not an issue with layer. As I found later, the problem was on the server side. Back-end developers disabled video file streaming on their side.